# Joomla - Redirect all invalid token errors to login

Tags: php, joomla, http-redirect

Is it possible to redirect all invalid token errors encountered in my custom component to the login screen without hacking core Joomla files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this stage, unfortunately I don't believe there is.

Reading the thread on the Joomla forum at http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=466&t=265868&sid=cfddb2b734632e11c0b6df3327b6ca38&start=180, many solutions have been proposed.

Which Joomla version are you encountering it on?

I'm going to push to have it addressed as a feature to be resolve in Joomla 3.3, as it is singularly one of the most common issues my Joomla clients encounter repeatedly.

Comment: I'm on 3.2. Yeah it seems a bit strange that you can't redirect because what are site visitors meant to do with that information! Log in again? Why not redirect with the message...???

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a plugin which was made for that:

[Token Interceptor Joomunited plugin](http://joomunited.com/products/token-interceptor)

Be carefull to use in your component the default message token like that (in fact like joomla):

```
<?php die(JText::_('JINVALID_TOKEN')); ?>
```